# Giving margin/padding is affecting col-sm-n. How to avoid this in bootstrap4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to display records in cards, i Want each row contains just 3 cards such that there should be marginal space between these cards. But when I gave mr-n it will move some cards to next row. All I want is to display 3 cards in a row such that there should be some space horizontally between them. Could anyone please help me on this?

```
 @if(count($supervisors)>0)
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (...)
            <div class="card col-sm-4">
               <img class="card-img" src="" alt="Image Here">

               <div class="card-body ">

               </div>
            </div>
         @endforeach
    </div>
@else
    <p>No Supervisor Available</p>
@endif
@endSection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution. Col-sm-n class in bootstrap takes care of margins so all we have to do is add another div(parent) of card, and give parent div class of 'col-sm-4', and it will sort it out :)